# Json Deserialize abstract class $type in string

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize using newtonsoft deserializeobject the below json, but I get the error below. How can I make it use the type it declares in the json with that $type bit? The error is true as the VisitType class is the base abstract class for a number of classes, FormType being one of them.

> Could not create an instance of type Messages.VisitType. Type is an
>   interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
>   'tasks[0].Id', line 1, position 103.

```
{
    "isFullyComplete":true,
    "tasks":[
              {
                 "$type":"Messages.FormType, Messages",
                 "Id":{"ref":"CP"},
                 "status":"Complete"
              }
            ],
     "identity":
              {
                "guid":"3fd3b1c2-c700-e911-8080-005056883684"
              },
              "proRef":"No"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

And just when I'd spent ages looking I finally found the answer:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm